# How to set screen resolution for 1440 X 2880 and 1440 X 2560 in android?

Tags: android, screen, resolution

I have one designing in android that images are showing different in 1440 X 2880 screen and 1440 X 2560 screen. How to do this correctly? Specially for the  screen 1440 X 2880. I have created hdpi, mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi images still i am not getting the result.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0enter code here" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar_logo"
             android:id="@+id/relToolbar">
    </include>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relToolbar"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/test"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/im1"
        android:background="@drawable/ranking"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/im1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/coin"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

An images are from the .psd to .png with the help of adobe Xd tool I need design like first snap in image

Comment: You need to be more specific about the end result: How should the image look? I can see that the screen doesn't look the same across all devices but it is hard to say how it should look.
Also, there are just too many ways in which this may be happening. Without knowing what you have tried so far and without seeing any relevant code, helping you becomes a game of educated guessing.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: If I understand correctly your problem is with the horizontal space that is between your blue and green views on the right, and the white view on the left? What would you like to happen? Should the white view expand to cover that space?

Comment: No, I want both should expand equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what has been said on the comments I think your problem comes from misunderstanding how to set constraint to views using android layouts and views, and not from the resolution of the screens you're working on. Reading on the topic will surely help you out.

I see two solutions to your problem, both of them include changing the layout you're using. On one hand, you could change your `RelativeLayout` for a `LinearLayout` and google some tutorial on view weights, and on the other hand you could use the more modern `ConstraintLayout` and read a little about how linear groups and chains work.

I'll leave links to the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear#Weight) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#constrain-chain) to help you get started